# How to search multiple Projects in GitLab

Tags: search, gitlab, multiple-projects

I am trying to find a way to search multiple project's code in gitlab CE.

Has anyone encountered this before, or have a recommended approach?

(I realize that if this is even possible, then I would likely need to create a script that mimics the current call from the GUI multiple times and combine the results. )

Answer (score -2):

Recently came into a similar need.  My particular use case is a self-hosted instance of GitLab CE.  Seems like it's possible to use GitLab's API where the scope is limited to snippet, then loop through your groups and projects.

Example code:

```
https:// (instance_server) /search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&snippets=&scope=&search= (key words) &group_id=22&project_id=81
```

Other links:

GitLab's paid version. 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/advanced_search_syntax.html#syntax-search-filters

Mention of original request (closed)
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14597
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/search-code-across-all-projects/2263  (SourceGraph)

Answer (score -3):

If you want to (or are okay with) searching *all* of the projects in a single GitLab (Enterprise?) instance, the existing search feature (as-of 2023-4-22) can do this.

If you're using a shared GitLab instance (e.g. `gitlab.com`), right now, AFAIK, the only way to do this in the existing GitLab UI is to create a group, migrate or move all of the projects you want to search to that group, and then search just that group. (Yes, this is or can be a steep cost, and it's an annoying requirement.)

Otherwise, you'll need to find (e.g. [this](https://github.com/phillipj/gitlab-search)) or develop some kind of tool to use the GitLab search API for the projects you want to search and then combine the results somehow:

- [Develop with GitLab | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/)

Search (REST) API:

- [Search API | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/search.html)